# On Every Gird view row data will bind in different condtion

Tags: asp.net

I have one GridView. and bind data in the grid view. In Grid View there is Drop DownList and in this drop down list there is two values bind One is Bank And other is Cash.
When user will choose bank from Drop Down List which is in Gridview  then Bank Account No. , Bank Name will show in the grid view on that particular Row.
If Second Row User Choose Cash then One Text Box Will show for voucher no.

Then How i can manage every grid view row data according the user choose.

If Grid View First Row User Choose Bank Then infront of that particular row Bank Name Drop Down list and account no will bind.

If Grid View Second Row User Choose Cash Then infront of that particular row Voucher No will show.

If Grid View First Row User Choose Bank Then infront of that particular row Bank Name Drop Down list and account no will bind.

If Grid View Third Row User Choose Bank Then infront of that particularrow Bank Name Drop Down list and account no will bind.

Answer (score 0):

Use EditItemtemplates With 2 controls one control is drop down for binding account  number and other control for Voucher number (Textbox Contol). Check With the item command name. If the user selects Bank drop down then hide text box control or if the user select cash then hide the account number dropdown.